# how to replace symbols using regex.sub in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `s`, where:

```
s = 'id=,value=<<<,RMOrigin=[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue=<<<ABCRMGrade=[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue='
```

I want to replace ABC with DEF when ever

```
<<<ABC\w+=\[0]>>>
```

occurs then output should be

```
<<<DEF\w+=\[0]>>>
```

in text \w+ refers to  RMGrade but this changes randomly

desired ouput is:

```
S = id=,value=<<<,RMOrigin=[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue=<<<ABCRMGrade=[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue=
```

i have tried in way of:

```
 s = re.sub('<<<ABC\w+=\[0]>>>','<<<DEF\w+=\[0]>>>',s)
```

i'm output as

```
 'id=,value=<<<,RMOrigin=[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue=<<<DEF\\w+=\\[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue='
```

Comment: What in this code is a string and what not? Why don't you use strings-delimiters? Your code currently only gives syntax errors. Please create a [mcve] that displays your problem.

Comment: Your title says `regex.sub` but your code uses `re.sub`. Can we assume you are asking about the standard library `re` module, not the third-party `regex` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused what you exactly want to achieve. But if you want to replace `ABC` in every match of pattern `<<<ABC\w+=\[0]>>>`, then you can use backreferences to groups.

For example, modify pattern so that you can reference the groups `(<<<)ABC(\w+=\[0]>>>)`. Now group#1 refers to the part before `ABC` and group#2 refers to part after `ABC`. So the replacement string looks like this - `\1DEF\2` - where `\1` is group#1 and `\2` is group#2.

```
import re

s = 'id=,value=<<<,RMOrigin=[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue=<<<ABCRMGrade=[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue='

res = re.sub(r'(<<<)ABC(\w+=\[0]>>>)', r'\1DEF\2', s)
print(res)
```

The output: `id=,value=<<<,RMOrigin=[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue=<<<DEFRMGrade=[0]>>>BasicData:id=ABCvalue=`

You also can use function to define replacement. For more check in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: Thankyou Mr.Mike kaskun

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.